# How to get my shot delay to work

Tags: c#, timer, delay, wait, unity-game-engine

I was trying to learn how to do this with gamesplusjames on youtube but it's not working out too well. I'm pretty sure it's something minor but I can't figure out what it is. Basically my character aims her bow and arrow and shoots when I release the C key. But i need a delay so she doesn't shot faster than her animations can move. Can anyone tell me where I dropped the ball? I simplified my code to get rid of all the other junk that doesn't have to do with the shooting or aiming. Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class tulMove : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform arrowSpawn;
public GameObject arrowPrefab;

private bool aim = false;
private bool shot = false;

public float shotDelay;
private float shotDelayCounter;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;

void Start ()
{

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update(){

    if (!aim && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C))
    {
        aim = true;
        anim.SetTrigger ("aim");
    }

    if (aim && !shot && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.C)) 
    {

        shot = true;
        aim = false;
        anim.SetTrigger ("shot");
        Instantiate (arrowPrefab, arrowSpawn.position, arrowSpawn.rotation);
        shotDelayCounter = shotDelay;
    }

    if (aim && !shot && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.C)) 
    {
        shotDelayCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (shotDelayCounter <= 0) 
        {
            shotDelayCounter = shotDelay;
            shot = true;
            aim = false;
            anim.SetTrigger ("shot");
            Instantiate (arrowPrefab, arrowSpawn.position, arrowSpawn.rotation);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the video, and describe what is currently going wrong? As in, are you implying that the animation currently goes too fast?

Comment: Well the video isn't fitting my situation exactly but sure. It's like 20 minutes but he just does the timer thing in the first couple minutes and then moves onto making health, which isn't relevant. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6hUIU72JwE

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm just trying to get a timer to work basically. Right now i'm not getting results. I can adjust the amount of time it takes for the next arrow to come out using a float which isn't a problem. getting the code to work in the first place is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is structured right now, the `shotDelayCounter` only gets called when its `if` statement is true and it looks like that is not true all the time. Move the `shotDelayCounter -= Time.deltaTime;` outside of the if statement so it will be called each frame. Something like:

```
shotDelayCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

if (aim && !shot && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.C) && shotDelayCounter <= 0) 
{
    shotDelayCounter = shotDelay;
    shot = true;
    aim = false;
    anim.SetTrigger ("shot");
    Instantiate (arrowPrefab, arrowSpawn.position, arrowSpawn.rotation);
}
```

Now your counter should be working correctly as it will always be called

Comment: The joy...the pure...joy inside right now. thanks dude.